# How to check float using isinstance in Python?

Tags: python

I cannot make sense of below:
 When I check the type of "RUN_ID", it clearly states "float". But when I check if it is float, it returns False. 
What is this type exactly and how to check?

```
tags.loc[0, 'RUN_ID']
Out[36]: 38607.0   
type(tags.loc[0, 'RUN_ID'])
Out[34]: float 
isinstance(type(tags.loc[0, 'RUN_ID']),np.float64)
Out[32]: False
isinstance(type(tags.loc[0, 'RUN_ID']),np.float32)
Out[33]: False

isinstance(type(tags.loc[0, 'RUN_ID']),float)
Out[35]: False
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using `isinstance` wrong. Instead of

```
isinstance(type(tags.loc[0, 'RUN_ID']),float)
```

just do

```
isinstance(tags.loc[0, 'RUN_ID'],float)
```

The `type()` function returns an object of type `type`, where you want the type of the object itself.

Comment: maybe more accurate to say that `type()` has been used improperly instead of `isinstance()`

Answer (score 3):

check with the regular float type instead of numpy. Test results below

```
w = isinstance(n, float)    # True
x = isinstance(n, np.float32)   # False
y = isinstance(n, np.float64)   # False
z = type(n) == float        # True
```

Answer (score 2):

```
isinstance(type(tags.loc[0, 'RUN_ID']),float)
```

returns false because `type(tags.loc[0, 'RUN_ID'])` returns `float`, which is actually of type `type`. You can verify that by saying something like

```
type(type(tags.loc[0, RUN_ID']))
```

So you're actually checking to see if the type of the type `float` is the same as the type `float`, which is `False`.

So maybe try

```
isinstance(tags.loc[0, 'RUN_ID'],float)?
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe isinstance() checks more if a value is a certain class rather than if two class values are the same.

For example, `isinstance(0.35, float)` returns True.

The way you have it is basically asking "Is the type float an instance of a float?" which is not correct.